# How to view the tail of a log file in Windows?

Tags: windows-xp, log-files, file-associations

What's an efficient way to view the last N lines of a large log file in Windows XP?

Would it be possible to then associate this method with `.log` files when double-clicked in Explorer?

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at ["Tail for Windows"](http://tailforwin32.sourceforge.net/). It boasts the following features on their web page:

> A few features of Tail:
>   * Watch multiple files in realtime
>   * Detect keyword matches, and highlight occurrences
>   * Send mail notifications on keyword matches by SMTP or MAPI
>   * Plugin architecture allows you to write specialized handlers
>   * Can process files of any size on all types of drive (local or networked)

Answer (score 1):

The tail.exe from the Windows 2003 Resource Kit is very limited and does not support the same functionality as its Unix/Linux counterpart.

Check out the UnxUtils.  It is native port to Win32 and does not have any external dependenies.

Answer (score 0):

Tail Ace is the program

Comment: The realtime update feature sounds helpful, though I'm a little surprised that its 6.6Mb! Will check it out...

Answer (score 0):

[Baretail](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/) is quick nice and small

Answer (score 0):

you could also get the tail.exe from MS themselves: [resource kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&displaylang=en) (shocking I know, but sometimes they do have the right tools, you just have to know where to find them).